# How to update _id in Mongodb Replica Set configuration?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I had 5 mongo members in Replica Set. After I deleted 3 from it.

How can I change "_id" in others members to values "0", "1" and "2"?

```
rs.conf()
{
        "_id" : "rs0",
        "version" : 151261,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "host" : "mongodb3:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 4,
                        "host" : "mongodb4:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 5,
                        "host" : "ok:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : true
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Macindows I did not find

Answer (score 0):

Directly editing the replica set configuration may not be an elegant way. Instead use the `rs.remove(hostname)` command to remove a member from replica set , this way you need not have to bring down the primary during reconfiguration which will automatically assign ascending order values to "_id" field.

Comment: I do not quite understand the steps. I tried to remove one member, but after this member automatically takes old value of _id (4 or 5)

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the slaves collection as described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-replica-sets/#duplicate-key-error-on-local-slaves

The master will recreate the collection the next time it is required.

Comment: This option was removed mongo 4+

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in the Mongo console:

```
conf = rs.conf()

conf.members[0]._id = 0
conf.members[1]._id = 1
conf.members[2]._id = 2

rs.reconfig(conf)
```

Comment: That is obviously the first thing I tried but got the error "New and old configurations both have members with host of HOST:27017 but in the new configuration the _id field is MemberId(0) and in the old configuration it is MemberId(4) for replica set setname"